# Using sed to generate multiple files, names of which dependent on regex pattern searched for

Tags: sed

Essentially I've got a mis-ordered file I want reconstruct. Common is a section pattern P which in regex terms is `^\d\{1,2}\\.\d\{1,2}\\.\d\{1,2}\\.` i.e: `1.2.3.` and following is some text.

What I want is to output these section blocks into seperate files so I can reconstruct them in order.

My strategy so far (because I'm not able (yet) to handle multi-line regex) is to

1. Replace those patterns P with the same pattern preceded by 6 `&` characters (as markers)
2. Then replace all the newlines with some other marker pattern, say `###`
3. Then (and this is where I'm having trouble), with `sed`, search for anything of the form `&&&P[any characters]&&&` and output this to a file appended with a number whose value is P (i.e. `file1.2.3`)
4. Merge these files back into one file correctly ordered (not quite sure how to do this but that's not what is blocking me yet)
5. Remove the `&` markers and replace the `###` with new lines.

I realise this is probably an inefficient way of going about it, but with the knowledge I have yet, were it not for steps (3) and perhaps (4) I believe I would at least achieve my objective.

As for (3) I've tried derivatives of:
`sed s/\\(\&\&\&\\)\\(^\d\{1,2}\\.\d\{1,2}\\.\d\{1,2}\\.\\)\\(.*\&\&\&/\\)/\1\2\3/ < somefile > file\2`

Where I'm trying to use the regex pattern `\2` as an extension to my a new file; and, well, it's not working at all!

**Note:** I use 6 `&` so I don't pick out patterns of the form `&&`

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've edited the question to add code tags. And I suggest you to provide some input sample and output expected, because it was difficult for me to guess what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is fair to say that `sed` is not the correct tool for this task.  With enough effort, it could probably be made to do it, but it really isn't fair to make it do so.

Perl (or Python) is a reasonable alternative.  I'm more fluent in Perl than Python, so I'd use that.

Further, with Perl, you probably don't even need to send the output to multiple files, unless the document is hundreds of megabytes in size.

I'm reading between the lines a bit, but I think your document input format is something like:

```
2.1.9
...multiple lines of material for section 2.1.9...
1.3.6
...multiple lines of material for section 1.3.6...
9.1.3
...multiple lines of material for section 9.1.3...
```

Where the sections are not presented in order. It isn't crucial to my suggestion that the section tag is on a line on its own; it marginally alters things if there is text on the same line.

In outline, the code should look like:

```
my $current_section = "0.0.0";
my %section_list = ();
my $section_material = "";

while (<>)
{
    if (m/^(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/)
    {
        # Found a new section...stash the old one...
        if ($section_material ne "")
        {
            # If the same section number appears twice, simply concatenate
            # the new material over the old.  Or you can get more complex,
            # using an array of refs to section material...
            $section_list{$current_section} = ""
                if !defined $section_list{$current_section}; 
            $section_list{$current_section} .= $section_material;
            $current_section = $1;
            $section_material = "";
        }
    }
    $section_material .= $_;
}
if ($section_material ne "")
{
    $section_list{$current_section} = ""
        if !defined $section_list{$current_section}; 
    $section_list{$current_section} .= $section_material;
}

# Now the hash %section_list contains all the material.
# You need a section number comparison function that can be used with sort
sub section_cmp
{
    ...if $a comes before $b...return -1
    ...if $b comes before $a...return +1
    ...otherwise...............return 0
}

foreach my $section (sort section_cmp keys %section_list)
{
     print "[$section]\n";
     print "$section_list{$section}\n";
}
```

And now you have the output with the sections in sorted order, without any intermediate files.

The code is outline.  I have not Perl-ized it wholly; it probably isn't minimal.  In particular, the futzing with ensuring `$section_list{$current_section}` is empty if its not been used before could easily be paranoid overkill.  The other details I'd have to check carefully are the invocation of the comparison function in the `sort` and the mechanics of the comparison function.

---

The comparison code below works as I expect it to.  I'm not certain there isn't a clever way to do the comparison more succinctly, but working beats non-working.  It is an independent little program with test-case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ( "3.1.6", "1.2.9", "7.4.5", "2.1.3",   "10.1.2",  "1.1.1",
              "1.1.3", "1.4.9", "1.4",   "1.4.9.1", "1.10.13", "1.1.13" );

# For use from sort - data 'passed' as $a and $b
sub paranum_cmp
{
    my(@v1) = split /\./, $a;
    my(@v2) = split /\./, $b;
    my($l1) = scalar @v1;
    my($l2) = scalar @v2;
    my($len) = ($l1 < $l2) ? $l1 : $l2;

    for (my $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        return -1 if ($v1[$i] < $v2[$i]);
        return +1 if ($v1[$i] > $v2[$i]);
    }
    return -1 if ($l1 < $l2);
    return +1 if ($l1 > $l2);
    return 0;
}

print "Before:\n";
foreach my $v (@array) { print "$v\n"; }
@array = sort paranum_cmp @array;
print "After:\n";
foreach my $v (@array) { print "$v\n"; }
```

You might look up v-numbers, or find a 'version comparison' module that would do the job faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you might be asking a little too much from sed. Your approach might work, but perl has tools made for the job:

```
while ( $line = <> ) {
    if( $line =~ /\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/ ) {
        $section = $1;
        open( $SECTION, ">>", "out.$section.txt");
        print $SECTION $line;
        close $SECTION;
    }
}
```

This is the brute force method... I'm opening and closing file handles inside the while loop, which is horribly inefficient. This would be sufficient for something that you're going to run a handful of times on a file of less than 10000 lines. Note that this solution appends data to each file, so you'll have to clear out all of the files if you want to run it again.

It would be better to create a hash of all of the possible output file names, then create an array of lines for each file name. These could be sorted and written out, file by file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Barton, I don't fully understand the finer details of your code yet (because I really am new to perl (at the moment that is)) but I'll have a go with this tomorrow (with a cut down file for testing purposes) and let you know how I get on with it. As regards the inefficiency you mention, would I be correct in saying this algorithm is order n^2 (for n the number of lines)? Your Other solution looks good, but again, it looks like I'll have some learning ahead of me before I can implement it.

Comment: No, it should be O(N)... it's just that opening and closing file handles can be slow, because you're (potentially) hitting the disk every time that you do it.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` can do this fairly elegantly:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk

# Put anything before the first section somewhere so we don't lose it.
BEGIN { section = "pre" }

# When we hit a new section, change to that section. Print the section to a file, for sorting later.
/^([0-9]{1,2}\.){3}/ { print (section=$0) >> "sections" }

# Print the line into the current working file
{ print >> section }
```

Now after running this, each section is in its own file, named after the section. Let's combine them.

```
# print the preamble if there was any
[ -f pre ] && cat pre > full

# sort has a -V option to sort version numbers, which is what you want.
sort -V sections | while read file; do cat "$file" >> full; done
```

And that's it. You have your complete file, sorted by section, with all preamble still at the top.